# How to check the following inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, oscillatory-integral

Assume $\chi_+$ is a smooth cut-off function away from origin, more precisely, it is defined as below:
\begin{equation}
\chi_+(\lambda)=
\begin{cases}
1, &  \lambda - \mu > 2\lambda_1, \\
0, & \lambda- \mu \le \lambda_1,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_1 >0$ is a small number and $\mu >0$ is a fixed constant, then how can we check the following equality:
\begin{equation}
\sup_{a \in \mathbb{R} } \| [\chi_+(\lambda^2+\mu) \cos(\lambda a)]^\vee \|_{\mathscr{M}} <\infty,
\end{equation}
where $\|\cdot \|_{\mathscr{M}}$ stands for the total variation norm of measures.

And my question is as follows:

- How can we check the inequality above?
- Why the auther tended to use $\|\cdot  \|_{\mathscr M}$ rather than just the $L^1$-norm, what is the difference between them?

The question is origined from the estimates of $(233)$ in [Wilhelm Schlag: Stable manifolds for an orbitally unstable NLS](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405435).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @supinf Sorry to reply you so late. To be honest, I do not have some mature ideas about it. Heuristically speaking, I tend to write it as the form of convolution, $(\chi_+ (\lambda^2+\mu))^\vee * (\cos(\lambda a))^\vee $ and then using Young's inequality. But I do not know how to deal with the total variation of these two terms.

Comment: @supinf As for the latter, it can be regarded as dirac measure, but I have searched something about it, some people said that it equals 1, but other said it equals to $\infty$, so I was a little confused about it. As for the former, I totally have no idea about it since it is supported on the whole interval away from origin and thus I cannot figure out the explicit representation of the Fourier transform of $\chi_+ (\lambda^2+\mu)$.